# Having a cannot find symbol error and one other

Tags: java, list, methods

I'm getting 2 cannot find symbol errors and it doesn't seem to be the result of the class path. I also am having a problem getting my .add method from the listinterface.java code to work in my pex6.java. I don't know if it's because im using an integer for the type and the add method is void but i'm not sure. Iv'e been working with java for about 6 months now so i'm still very new to it. Let me know if something is missing.

```
public interface ListInterface<T>
{


/**
 * Should return the number of elements contained within this list:
 */`enter code here`
int size ();


/**
 * Should return true if this list contains a copy of the given object:
 *
 * Comparisons should be performed by calling the equals(...) method of
 * each element, passing the given object as an argument
 */
boolean contains ( T theObject );


/**
 * Should remove the first element found within this list that exists as a
 * copy of the given object and return true if such an element was found:
 */
boolean remove ( T theObject );


/**
 * Should return a reference to the first element found within this list
 * that exists as a copy of the given object or null if no such element was
 * found:
 */
Object get ( T element );


/**
 * Should return a nicely formatted string representation of this list:
 */
String toString ();


/**
 * Should print the contents of this list to the screen:
 */
void writeLinkedList ();


/**
 * Should initialize this list for iteration (use of the getNext() method):
 */
void reset ();


/**
 * Should return a reference to the element located at the iterator's
 * current position and increment the iterator:
 *
 * If the iterator is currently pointing to the last element in this list,
 * the iterator should be reset to point to the first element in this list.
 *
 * @Preconditions:
 *     This list is not empty.
 *     This list has been reset.
 *     This list has not been modified since the last reset.
 */
  T getNext ();


/**
 * Should insert the given object onto the front of this list:
 */
void add ( T theObject );

}



public class PEX6
{
public static void main (String[] theArgs)
    {
        ListInterface<String> list = new RefList<T>();


            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++);
                {
                    int Random = ( ( int ) ( Math.random() * 4 ) );
                    list.add(new Integer(Random));

                    list.writeLinkedList();
                }
    }
private static int CountValue(ListInterface<T> theList,int theValue)
    {
        theList.clear();
        Integer nFound = 20;


        return nFound;
    }

}
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\Linville\Documents\Assignment 6\PEX6.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    private static int CountValue(ListInterface<T> theList,int theValue)
                                                ^
  symbol:   class T
  location: class PEX6
C:\Users\Linville\Documents\Assignment 6\PEX6.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
            ListInterface<String> list = new RefList<T>();
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class T
  location: class PEX6
C:\Users\Linville\Documents\Assignment 6\PEX6.java:11: error: method add in interface ListInterface<T> cannot be applied to given types;
                        list.add(new Integer(Random));
                            ^
  required: String
  found: Integer
  reason: actual argument Integer cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface ListInterface
3 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

By the way the PEX6.java isn't finished by any means but I want to go ahead and get the code compiling correctly, so that I don't end up with a lot of errors to fix when i'm done.

Comment: Hint: `ListInterface<String> list = new RefList<T>();` should be `ListInterface<String> list = new RefList<String>();`

Comment: What have you written so far for PEX6.java?

Comment: Thank you for the help with the add method. The only thing left now is the cannot find symbol errors. To answer the question you ask qparyani I have written all the code for the pex6 class. I'm not done with it because I have to write the countvalue method.

Comment: Ok i fixed everything thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `T` in `PEX6`, yet you're referring to it:

```
ListInterface<String> list = new RefList<T>();
                                         ^ here

private static int CountValue(ListInterface<T> theList,int theValue)
                                            ^ and here
```

You need to replace `T` with either `String` or `Integer`. It's impossible to tell which of the two is intended: you declare `list` as `ListInterface<String>` and then proceed to add `Integers` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a Type for T.
eg. if you want the ListInterface to be a list of Strings

`private static int CountValue(ListInterface<String> theList,int theValue)`